# Return an object from an array of objects for a specific URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-tag-manager

I have a somewhat complicated issue. I'm working for a client that has an array of objects available for every lead on their website (e.g. contact form submission, newsletter signup etc.).

I'm currently working in Google Tag Manager to solve this issue. In order to let my client create their own events, I'm setting up a Tag Manager template where he can create these objects themselves.

However, I want to tie a specific object to a specific action. So if he creates the following object:

```
var obj1 = {name: 'test', page = 'example.com/test'}
```

I want this object to only work on that specific page. I know how to create this in JavaScript with a number of if/else statements. But I don't want to adjust the code every time he comes with a new action.

These actions use specific 'thank-you' or 'confirmation' pages to trigger an event on. I'm currently working on a way to push one of these objects whenever someone signs up. For example:

```
var obj1 = {name: 'newsletter', page = 'example.com/thank-you-newsletter'}
var obj2 = {name: 'contact_form', page = 'example.com/sign-up-contact'}
```

At the moment, there is no way of restructuring this. So, I was thinking the following:

```
var page = 'example.com/thank-you-newsletter'; //current page
var userSubmittedURL = 'example.com/thank-you-newsletter'; //given by me

list = [];

if (page === userSubmittedURL) {

list.push(obj1)

}
```

This userSubmittedURL changes all the time, is there a way to create a specifc object for a specifc page without adjusting the code all the time?

Comment: So is there any rule we can predict in this stage for this `userSubmittedURL` ? Seems like you want `If someone signup the form on any possible page. Create a object according to that page`

Comment: Exactly that. I know the issue is somewhat vague!

Comment: I think we need to narrow down the possible rule. Or the client can modify the url for you? Maybe the url can bring some ?the_form_key_tracking={form_name}. Then you can listen if the url has the parameter `the_form_key_tracking`

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to store the page information in another source (like a text file) and then load it dynamically using ajax. Here is an example from w3Schools (https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_first)

```
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    this.responseText;
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt");
  xhttp.send();
```

In onload, rather than setting an elements innerHTML, you can use `this.responseText` to get your url